# How to fix Next.js error "cancel rendering route"?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to link to a div id and I get this error: `Error: Cancel rendering route`

This seems to be a problem with double linking.

I'm already using `useRouter` to `push` to a [slug], since `NextLink` and `<a>` don't cause a re-render in the map loop, which I'm using to render the content that matches(endsWith) with `asPath: /posts/post-id/the-slug`

```
  const router = useRouter();
  const { asPath } = useRouter();
  const {
    query: { id },
  } = useRouter();

  const handleHref = (link) => {
    router.push(link);
  };
```

This works, link to slugs that also re-renders the map loop.

```
  <ButtonLink
    onClick={() =>
      handleHref(
        `/posts/${id}/${String(item.slug).replace(/ /g, "-")}`
      )
    }
  >
    Example
  </ButtonLink>
```

Now when trying to link to a div id `/posts/post-id/the-slug#div-id` using the same method with `useRouter` or `NextLink`, I get the error.

```
  <Link href={`#${String(sect.section).replace(/ /g, "-")}`} passHref>
    <a>
      <Text>Example</Text>
    </a>
  </Link>

  //or

  <ButtonLink
    onClick={() =>
      handleHref(`/posts/${id}/${String(
        item.slug
      ).replace(/ /g, "-")}#${String(
        sect.section
      ).replace(/ /g, "-")}`)
    }
  >
    Example
  </ButtonLink>
```

Edit: After the first click on one of the ButtonLink in the map loop, I can't push new hash from the others.

```
<div>
  <ButtonLink
    onClick={() =>
      handleHref(`/posts/${id}/${String(item.slug).replace(/ /g, "-")}`)
    }
  >
    Example
  </ButtonLink>
    
  {posts.map((item) => {
    if (
      asPath.startsWith(
        `/posts/${id}/${String(item.slug).replace(/ /g, "-")}`
      )
    )
      return (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <div>
            {item.section.map((sect) => {
              <div key={sect.id}>
                <ButtonLink
                  onClick={() =>
                    handleHref(
                      `#${String(sect.section).replace(/ /g, "-")}`
                    )
                  }
                >
                  {sect.name}
                </ButtonLink>
              </div>;
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
  })}
</div>
```

Comment: @ivanatias v.12

Comment: I think this is not documented but `router.push` actually returns a promise, so can you try modifying `handleHref` so it receives as params both the route path and the hash and do like: `router.push(path).then(() => if (hash) router.push(hash))` and see if that works?

Comment: @ivanatias It didn't work, maybe I did it wrong. In my `handleHref`, I'm pushing "link", should, path and hash in your code all be link or where hash coming from?

Comment: In the example I'm providing, `link` and `hash` should be passed both to `handleHref`, so for example, let's say the path or link is `/aboutme` and the hash would be something like `#myskills`. You pass both to `handleHref` and do as I commented above: `handleHref(path, hash)`.

Comment: @ivanatias Thank you very much, that worked! You should post that as answer so I can mark it as the answer to my post.

Comment: @ivanatias I got a little problem the link(hash) doesnt change after the first one is clicked within the map loop.

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand what you mean with this new issue, can you update your question to include the new implementation and also fully describe this new problem?

Comment: Don’t store app state in the URL with the Next.js router https://guillermodlpa.com/blog/dont-store-app-state-in-url-with-nextjs-router

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting the same error using Link like this:

```
 const onSignOut = (event:any) => {
    auth.signout();
 }
 ...
 <Link href='#'  onClick={onSignOut}
```

`auth.signout()` do an implicit `router.push('/login')`

I think in my case the error is getting because it is trying to route to `#` and `/login` at the same time.

My solution was add a `preventDefault` to click handler:

```
const onSignOut = (event:any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    auth.signout();
}
```